# How to change middle value in a color index?

Tags: r, viridis

I want to reproduce the following plot from here:

[image: desired plot]

plot with cm.colors(255):
[image: plot with cm.colors(255)]

```
ImagePlot <- function(x, ...){
 min <- min(x)
 max <- max(x)
 layout(matrix(data=c(1,2), nrow=1, ncol=2), widths=c(1,7), heights=c(1,1))

 ColorLevels <- cm.colors(255)

 # Color Scale
 par(mar = c(1,2.2,1,1))
 image(1, seq(min,max,length=255),
  matrix(data=seq(min,max,length=255), ncol=length(ColorLevels),nrow=1),
  col=ColorLevels,
  xlab="",ylab="",
  xaxt="n")
    
 # Data Map
 par(mar = c(0.5,1,1,1))
 image(1:dim(x)[1], 1:dim(x)[2], t(x), col=ColorLevels, xlab="",
 ylab="", axes=FALSE, zlim=c(min,max))

layout(1)
}

#100x100 example
x <- c(seq(-10,10,length=255),rep(0,600))
mat <- matrix(sample(x,10000,replace=TRUE),nrow=100,ncol=100)
ImagePlot(mat)
```

I want to change the color scheme with viridis, there I change the line `ColorLevels <- cm.colors(255)` into `ColorLevels <- viridis::viridis(255)`. It worked but the zero is not white.

I try to change the median with the following but it only change about third quartile of it. Here is my attempt:

```
match(median(ColorLevels),ColorLevels)
  ColorLevels <- replace(ColorLevels, 178, '#FFFFFF')
```

This is the plot:
[image: plot]

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand. White is not part of the viridis colors. The plot looks confusing if you make white the color for zero. People will automatically assume that white indicates missing values. Anyway: `ColorLevels <- replace(ColorLevels, length(ColorLevels) %/% 2 + 1, '#FFFFFF') `

Comment: You also should specify `zlim` within `image`, so that the color scale is always symmetric.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Thank you! You are right, it is more confusing that way, never have imagined it before. It supposed to make people assume that white indicates zeroes, not missing values.